# Changing ClassName in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class

I know we can do many things like changing the current styles of an element, or changing its text etc. But, how can we change the *name* of the class using jQuery?

For example, the following CSS file has two different styles:

```
.roundedCorners {
  /* code for roundedCorners */
}

.NotSoRoundedCorners {
  /* code for NotSoRoundedCorners */
}
```

And the button looks like:

```
<input type="submit" class="NotSoRoundedCorners" value="Turn me on!" />
```

I know we can directly change its styles with a simple jQuery snip like this:

```
$('.closer').css({'visibility': 'hidden'}, 1000); // ETC.
```

But, what if there are many styles to change for the one element. Why not just have 2 style definitions in the CSS file, and when we need to change the style, just change the Class name of the element to the other style?

Comment: $.addClass and $.removeClass ? I thought it's too easy for posting it to S.O.

Comment: Use `.toggleClass()`. In your case `$('.closer').toggleClass('roundedCorners NotSoRoundedCornders');`

Comment: @jAndy: That is actually the best answer ;)

Comment: @J.T.S. Yes, changing the class name is the best way. What is your problem?

Comment: @Felix Kling - Thanks, yeah the problem was just that I wasn't even sure that you could change the classname.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should invoke jQuery's [`.toggleClass()`<sup>help</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) method.

Using that, you can explicitly *remove* and *add* a class to a node, leaving other classes untouched.

```
$('.closer').toggleClass('roundedCorners NotSoRoundedCornders');
```

---

Many guys here suggested to use `.attr()`, but that would replace the whole `className` attribute and therefore would overwrite/remove any given css class. I don't think thats the way to go.

Comment: +1 best answer :) There are special methods to handle classes so they are the way to go.

Comment: you scored dude best answer my +1

Comment: Didn't know about that method, definitely the best method.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. By using the attr method.

```
$('.NotSoRoundedCorners').attr('class', 'RoundedCorners');
```

Comment: you're overwritting all possibly set classes.

Comment: jAndy is right. This will clear out everything in the 'class' attribute, and you'll end up with only 'RoundedCorners'

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#yourid').removeClass("NotSoRoundedCorners").addClass("roundedCorners");
```

Comment: `.toggleClass()` is here for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.NotSoRoundedCorners').attr('class', 'RoundedCorners');
```

Comment: you're overwritting all possibly set classes.

Comment: as quoted by the J.T.S `we need to change the style, just change the Class name of the element to the other style?`

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
$('.closer').toggleClass('roundedCorners').toggleClass('NotSoRoundedCorners')
```

or

```
$('.closer').removeClass('roundedCorners');
$('.closer').addClass('NotSoRoundedCorners')
```

Comment: No need to invoke `.toggleClass` more than once here.

Comment: @jAndy, I noticed you wrote that in your answer. Felt like it would be 'stealing' to update my answer afterwards :) But you're right, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Really, why not?

```
$('.closer').addClass("roundedCorners);
$('.closer').removeClass("NotSoRoundedCorners );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.closer').removeClass('roundedCorners');
$('.closer').addClass('NotSoRoundedCorners')
```